# Google Chrome immediately closes whenever it is opened

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, macbook-air

I’m on a MacBook Air. I’ve restarted the laptop and reinstalled Google Chrome. Each time I try to open it, it pops up for a second then closes. I’ve tried opening the app through the terminal.

The terminal code says:

```
[bad_variant_access.cc : 44] RAW: Bad variant access \m
[10002:259:0407/161702.926188:FATAL:bad_variant_access.cc(44)]
Check failed: false. Bad variant access

[0407/161703.306872:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)]
UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5) Trace/BPT trap: 5 
logout
```

I can’t find any sort of crash report, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

Comment: If you start it in incognito mode, does it have the same problem?

Comment: Reinstalling does not correct corrupt user profiles. You should perform the test suggested above and, if successful, delete your profile and start over.

Comment: When you say 're-installed' what precisely did you do? Throwing the app away & getting a fresh copy is not a 're-install'. What macOS, what Chrome version?